# Django server rejecting all CURL requests but postman requests successful

Tags: curl, django-rest-framework

I just wanted to check why all my curl are getting rejected while postman requests working

Comment: Well, what's the difference in the response from the server when you make  CURL request vs. a Postman request?

Comment: When i run using postman it exactly fetches me the token but when i run using curl i get SSL_ERROR_ SYScall

Comment: The issue was in handling multiple request was not handled by django when i try with postman it maintains the connection and we cant use any other rest client. When I close the REST client the other REST client statts working